# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #5](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election/5) on Webmasters has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Maximillian Laumeister]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election/5) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6606935857037312).

Comment: Thank you Rosie. Looking forward to contributing as a community moderator!

Comment: Congratulations, @MaximillianLaumeister! Your speech was great, and I hope to learn by your example!

Comment: @MikeCiffone Your application was well-spoken too! The amount of great content you've contributed to Webmasters SE so far has been really impressive. It's not going unnoticed :)

Comment: Well done @MaximillianLaumeister!

Comment: Hah!  I hadn't seen the results post and was wondering what had happened.  Congratulations @MaximillianLaumeister

Comment: Thank you, @Steve!

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations, Maximillian Laumeister! Welcome to the team!

Comment: Thanks! Look forward to working alongside you as a moderator!

Answer (score 6):

All three candidates were terrific.  Max will make a great addition to our moderatior team, but I would have been happy to work with Mike Ciffone or davidgo.  This site is truly blessed to have multiple enthusiastic individuals who are willing to step up and take on a larger role.

Answer (score 6):

**Congratulations** to Max, and a **big thanks** to both davidgo and Mike Ciffone for stepping forward for the community and making the election possible. Your excellent contributions on the site and help to moderate it are really appreciated!